# New KafkaSpout Issue in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I have a basic topology includes kafka spout and and kafka bolts
When submit my topology ı gets this error in Storm UI

**Unable to get offset lags for kafka. Reason: org.apache.kafka.shaded.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: Topic '[enrich-topic]' is invalid**

I check **enrich-topic** is exist, there is no problem about that

```
    TopologyBuilder streamTopologyBuilder = new TopologyBuilder();

    KafkaSpoutRetryService kafkaSpoutRetryService =  new KafkaSpoutRetryExponentialBackoff(KafkaSpoutRetryExponentialBackoff.TimeInterval.microSeconds(500), KafkaSpoutRetryExponentialBackoff.TimeInterval.milliSeconds(2), Integer.MAX_VALUE, KafkaSpoutRetryExponentialBackoff.TimeInterval.seconds(10));

    KafkaSpoutConfig spoutConf =  KafkaSpoutConfig.builder(configProvider.getBootstrapServers(), configProvider.getSpoutTopic())
            .setGroupId("consumerGroupId")
            .setOffsetCommitPeriodMs(10_000)
            .setFirstPollOffsetStrategy(UNCOMMITTED_LATEST)
            .setMaxUncommittedOffsets(1000000)
            .setRetry(kafkaSpoutRetryService)
            .build();
    KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConf);
    streamTopologyBuilder.setSpout("kafkaSpout", kafkaSpout, 1);

    KafkaWriterBolt2 kafkaWriterBolt2 = null;
    try {
        kafkaWriterBolt2 = new KafkaWriterBolt2(configProvider.getBootstrapServers(), configProvider.getStreamKafkaWriterTopicName());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    streamTopologyBuilder.setBolt("kafkaWriterBolt2", kafkaWriterBolt2, 1).setNumTasks(1)
            .shuffleGrouping("kafkaSpout");
```

**KafkaWriterBolt2** is my class extends from BaseRichBolt